# TypeError: Cannot read property when passing in a prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am getting an issue

TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined in my Timeline.js file

when I pass in a prop to a react component and want to get a specific variable from my prop. To explain, timelineyears.js is the array of data that has a year variable that I want to pass into TimelineItem.js . Finally, Timeline.js will loop through all of the TimelineItem to show the years, but I am getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined when I compile. Any help would be much appreciated!

This is my timelineYears.js file

```html
const timelineYears = [{
        year: 1925

    },{
        year: 1926
    },
    {
        year: 1927
    }

];

export default timelineYears;
```

This is my timelineItem.js file

```html
import React from 'react';
import './timelineYears.js';


const TimelineItem = ({timelineYears}) => (
    <div className="timeline-item">
        <div className="timeline-item-content">
           {timelineYears.year}
        </div>   

    </div>

);

export default TimelineItem;
```

And finally, this is my Timeline.js file

```html
import React from 'react';
import timelineYears from  './timelineYears.js';
import TimelineItem from './TimelineItem.js';


const Timeline = () => timelineYears.length > 0 && (
    <div className="timeline-container">
        {timelineYears.map((data, idx) => (
            <TimelineItem data = {data} key={idx} />
        ))}
    </div>
);

export default Timeline;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `TimelineItem` component. According to your code, you're expecting a property called `timelineYears`, however, you're passing a property called `data`.

This should work:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './timelineYears.js';


const TimelineItem = ({data}) => (
    <div className="timeline-item">
        <div className="timeline-item-content">
           {data.year}
        </div>   
    </div>
);

export default TimelineItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your property is called `data` in Timeline.js. so when you deconstruct in TimelineItem, it should also be called data rather than timelineYears

So get rid of everything called timelineYears in TimelineItem and replace it with data

```
import React from 'react';


const TimelineItem = ({data}) => (
    <div className="timeline-item">
        <div className="timeline-item-content">
           {data.year}
        </div>   

    </div>

);

export default TimelineItem;
```